# Lost SF Short-Story, Solitary Human Explorer, too powerful to act. Alien POV

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, space-exploration, morality

This is ultimately a rather dark story.
It involves a solitary human explorer on an alien planet.
The human has an alien as an assistant, or he is helping the alien to travel
somewhere through tunnels.
They encounter several dangers along the way.
The story is told from the alien's point of view.
He seems amazed at how easily each danger is overcome by the human.
The story ends with the human leaving or being called away, possible to a war.
The human makes several comments that indicate a philosophy of great power leading to great responsibility.
The alien is left with the impression that humans are too strong to act.
I read this sometime in the 1970's-late 1980's.

Clarification: The human takes small actions, but refuses to make mass cultural changes or act to improve the life of the aliens, a form of Star Trek's Prime Directive, but less codified. The alien is, as I recall, angered that the human will not act more broadly, or teach them to.

Comment: I'm not certain I follow... it seems like the story has the human's actions being held in great esteem by the aliens, but he feels that humans cannot take action due to their power? Or is if a particular action?

Comment: Sounds similar to [Victory Unintentional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Unintentional).

Comment: I remember this one. Let me find the title. The human teaches them to make rocket launchers to fight against intelligent dinosaurs.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Victory Unintentional by Asimov. No, that was about Robotic Ambassadors visiting Jupiter. They neglected to mention that they were Robots leaving the Jovians with the impression that all Humans were Super-Strong and Invulnerable.

Comment: I am still uncertain if this is the correct answer. Please confirm that the Human and the Alien pass through tunnels and that the Human carelessly and easily kills various dangerous species that would pose a lethal problem to the alien. There may have been various musings on the ability to kill not being the right to kill, the alien of course understands nothing of this seeing the situation as a more black and white question of survival. I searched for hours for a synopsis of 'The Teacher' by Kapp with no results.

Comment: Human explorer finds humanoid aliens that are being driven to extinction by intelligent dinosaurs. They live in caves and tunnels for protection. The explorer is called The Gaffer by them and has a .45 ACP and an electric shocker. The humanoids already use an electroforming process to manufacture stuff and he teaches them how to make simple rocket launchers with it. The driver of the action is a Scorpid in the electro tank that they want the Gaffer to come and kill. He realizes he is deforming their culture.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I have now marked the original answer as correct. I am now almost certain this is the correct story. I will attempt to obtain a copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! It was [The Teacher](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51514) by [Colin Kapp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Kapp) and it was the cover story in [the August 1969 issue of Analog](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57061+c).

(I vaguely remembered the cover and looked at a collection of Analog covers and boomdiada, there it was.)